# Unable to determine if iframe or window in youtube export page (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create an automation wherein I can export a report from the Analytics tab from Studio.Youtube.

When I get to the page where I need to click the export button, nothing happens and it does not export the csv file. I have tried switching frames and windows but nothing happens.

Here is a sample of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

urlYoutube = "https://studio.youtube.com/"
urlStack = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"
username = "sample@gmail.com"
password = "samplepassword"

driver.get(urlStack)
googleButtonStack = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="openid-buttons"]/button[1]')
googleButtonStack.click()


userNameField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
userNameField.send_keys(username)


userNameNext = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/div[2]')
userNameNext.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)


passField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
passField.send_keys(password)

passFieldNext = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/div[2]')
passFieldNext.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get(urlYoutube)

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

analyticsButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-paper-icon-item-3"]')
analyticsButton.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# beforeWidnow = driver.current_window_handles

# print(beforeWidnow)

seeMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more-button"]/div')
seeMoreButton.click()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# newWindow = driver.current_window_handles

# print(newWindow)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/yta-explore-dialog/div'))



driver.implicitly_wait(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="export-button"]/iron-icon')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-button"]/iron-icon').click()


# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="text-item-1"]/ytcp-ve/div/div/yt-formatted-string'))).click()
```

Is there a way to click the export button and the options in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code by my own and it is working skipping the line

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/yta-explore-dialog/div'))
```

It is working fine even if you don't switch the frame.
If you want to export the csv you have to take the menu option

```
csv_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[contains(., 'Comma-separated values (.csv)')]")
```

and then click it

```
csv_option.click()
```

Comment: I tried removing some of the lines from my code and added yours, but it gives me the same error as before.

after calling the `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` after the button click on **See more** button, I added the line of code that you gave. It gave me this error? How did you make it work on your side?

`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//yt-formatted-string[contains(., 'Comma-separated values (.csv)')]"}`

Comment: Have you checked if the driver opens the dropdown up? If It doesn't, you could wait for the button `'//*[@id="export-button"]/iron-icon'` to be clickable

Comment: I got it already, I just needed to add `time.sleep()` in my code. It seems `implicitly_wait()` does not work and still goes very fast that's why it does not click the download button correctly. I have also added your code as the last line and it downloads the file. thank you